# If a cell has a certain value XXX, how do I delete the rows that don't have the value XXX?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In the posted example, if for Jane and David I'm only interested in rows with "Total" in column B, how do I remove the rows that do not contain "Total" in column B. I would like to apply this functionality to multiple sheets within a workbook.

[image: Example]

Comment: The easiest would be to "Filter" your results, highlight cells A1, B1 and C1 then use the "Filter" option in the "Sort & Filter" area of the "DATA" pane. If you want to know how many items have been picked then you want a COUNTIF() formula. This is a comment as your question is not that clear.

Comment: Sound like he want us to script him a VBA Function

Comment: Your title talks about deleting **columns**, but your question talks about deleting **rows**  Which is it???

Comment: Typically, totals are dynamic, not data.  If that's the case here, you would have to use filtering rather than deleting rows, otherwise the totals will be zero.

Answer (score 0):

Your simplest approach is to simply sort on the value you want and delete all the rows before that value, then all the ones after it which will leave only the rows with exactly it.

Of course, this being Excel, you can do each little bit of that slightly differently with wee bit more work. For instance, insert a "helper" column somewhere convenient (right next to your column of interest for example) and quickly write an IF test for the value with "" for failure to find it. Then copy, or fill, the entire column with the formula (each testing that row's cell), sort on the helper column and all the rows you want to delete are together rather than in two bunches. Which of your various options seems easier in your circumstance and preference is the way you might go.

If you need a macro to do it, follow the same concept. In the macro simply test the first cell in your column of interest for the value and if it is NOT found have the macro delete that row, then loop until you reach the end of data. If no cell can ever be blank in that column, you can test for blankness and quit when found. But... if a cell could be empty, you will need to try something else. Any of a variety of things could work depending upon your table and the other cells' characteristics, but you could also just start the macro on the last possible cell, chosen by your brain, and work upward (including a test for the row number each time so you can stop at, say, row 2 i fyou have headers rather than deleting our header row and then permanently looping on the first row).

Or combine the two. Sort the data on that column, in a macro, look for the first occurence of the desired value, delete all the DATA rows above that value, then test until the first failure, and delete all the rows afterwards.

So many ways. My approach would be the very first one for my own working. For a spreadsheet I'm giving to someone else to use, I'd modify that by trying to automate for him. Or... depends on the user, knowledgeable vs. newbie, boss vs. Jimmy from janitorial. That kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

*I would like to suggest a **MACRO,** which the best and fastest method to **Delete all rows** from **all the Sheets**, doesn't contains text **TOTAL** in specific **Column B**.*

```
Sub Delete_Rows()

Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, del As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet

For X = 1 To 10
    Set sht = Sheets(X)
    Set del = Nothing

    Set rng = Intersect(sht.Range("B1:B9"), sht.UsedRange)

    For Each cell In rng.Cells

    If (cell.Value) <> "Total" Then
        If del Is Nothing Then
            Set del = cell
        Else
            Set del = Union(del, cell)
        End If
    End If

    Next cell

    If Not del Is Nothing Then del.EntireRow.Delete
Next X

End Sub
```

**How it works:**

- At any Sheet Press `Alt+F11` to open `VB Editor` then `Copy & Paste` this Code as **Standard Module**.
- Before you **RUN** the *Macro*, insure that the Search String **Total** is available in Range `B1:B9` in *all the Sheets*, from where you are
  trying to **Delete Rows**.

**Note:**

- `For X = 1 to 10` indicated that MACRO will search `TOTAL` in `10 Worksheets`, which is editable.
- You may also adjust/alter the Search Range `B1:B9` and the String `Total` as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help. I ended up doing the following:

1. Use conditional formatting to highlight all cells with duplicate names
2. Sort cells by colour, then sort by name of apple
3. Shift select all rows containing a highlighted cell, that did not have "Total" in the apple column.

This process has been relatively quick for large datasets.

Comment: It's nice to find the Self Answer, it's your prerogative to opt the method but once you try the MACRO I've posted is TIME SAVER and a One Click Solution. ☺

Comment: You are right, and I will try the macro as well! I am embarrassingly intimidated by macros but am trying my best to learn. :)